# Use a custom module to add JS to every page in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, theming

How can I use a custom module to add JS to every page with Drupal 8?

I've found lots of example scattered over the internet that maybe used to work but no longer work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume the custom module is called example.

First create a example.libraries.yml file in your module root folder like this:

```
example:
  version: 1
  js:
    example.js: {}
  dependencies:
      - core/jquery
```

Next in example.module use [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8) too add your JS to every page:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function example_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'example/example';
}
```

So now the custom module has 4 files:

- example.module
- example.info.yml
- example.js
- example.libraries.yml

`hook_page_build()` and `hook_page_alter()` are now [deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2350949) so can no longer use them.

There is a [page drupal.org on adding CSS and JS using a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274843) with more information.

Comment: You will also need a `example.info.yml` file.

Comment: I am still learning Drupal 8 `$attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'example/example';` shouldn't the first example be the theme name?

Comment: No, this is how to add JS using a custom module, no theme is involved. The module name is repeated as there are no sections in the libraries yml. If however libraries.yml [looked like this](http://pastebin.com/raw/G8hwQqWG) then you would use example/core.

Comment: @FelixEve thanks for the explanation and posting this Q & A. I will definitely use this in the near future!

Comment: I know its an old post, but realy helped. Thanks @Felix Eve