# How can I avoid the output of my module is cached?

Tags: 8, caching, page-controller

I have a module I wrote that prints dynamic data for JavaScript variables.

```
function javascript_api_page_attachments(array &$page) {
$page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
        // The data.
    [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        // The HTML tag to add, in this case a  tag.
        '#tag' => 'script',
        // The value of the HTML tag, here we want to end up with alert("Hello world!");.
        '#value' => javascript_api_print_parameters(),

    ],
    // A key, to make it possible to recognize this HTML  element when altering.
    'hello-world'
];}
```

My problem is when Drupal caches the page.Need to stop caching my pages in drupal.

How can I avoid the output of my module is cached?

Comment: Why are you adding JavaScript like this?

Comment: Because all the variables are created by the module.

Comment: You have drupalSettings to pass variables.

Answer (score 3):

As Eyal mentioned, you can pass the variables from your module to jQuery like this:

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/auto';
    $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['cool'] = 'hello world';     
  }
}
```

**mymodule.libraries.yml**

```
auto:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    js/auto.js: {}
  dependencies:
      - core/jquery
```

**auto.js**

```
(function($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      alert(drupalSettings.cool);
    });

})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

This will show a js alert message saying "hello world".

Comment: Hi my problem is not in the way i am adding the js to the page .
my problem is this function: javascript_api_print_parameters() 
collect all the module the implement the hook and create a dynamic parameters . 
because drupal caching is enabled the first time you hit the page the parameters are sticky to this page .

Comment: @HanielBitton is this a custom page created by your module? or is this a content type node page?

Comment: its a regular node page.

Comment: @HanielBitton what data are you grabbing from the node page? or Exactly how does your dynamic data get created?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  you first create a Js file, put your Js function there then pass desire variable ( or object) to it with using `drupalSettings` and try to get variable(s)  in your js files. ( I guess you are know how attach js libraries to page if not take a took at [Helper1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197824/use-a-custom-module-to-add-js-to-every-page-in-drupal-8) and [Helper2](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)

```
$page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myvars'] = $myvars;
```

Then `Drupal.drupalSettings.myvar` will be exists (it's will be dynamic and not cached) in your Js file.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the page cache for anonymous users try the first method:

```
// Deny any page caching on the current request.    
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

Else, you need to set max-age 0 in e.g. hook_node_view().

```
function yourmodule_node_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'yourtype' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```

OR, if you like to remove cache from route, provide no_cache in `routing.yml` of your module.

```
newsletter.signup:
  path: '/abc'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\your_module\Controller\your_controller::render'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    no_cache: TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help i came up to create a new page with a controller and this page will be attached to the page .

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\javascript_api\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * An example controller.
 */
class PageParamsController extends ControllerBase {
    public function build(){
        $result = javascript_api_print_parameters();
        return new Response($result , 200 , array('Content-Type'=> 'application/javascript'));
    }}


pageparams:
  # Block the page from being loaded until Modernizr is initialized.
  header: true
  version: "v1"
  js:
    /javascript_api/pageparms.js: { preprocess: 0, weight: -21, minified: true }
```

Now i have a dyanmic js that i can put on the page and to use my Variable in the global area.

Thanks All :)

Comment: I don't think that the hook_page_attachments method will be cached. And it is always better to go with the framework than against it.

Comment: It actually been cached tried that when added the JavaScript to the head section.